# Overlay image on video using FFMPEG

Tags: php, ffmpeg, imagick

I'm trying to overlay an image on video using ffmpeg with php:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
    $video = $ffmpeg->open($videoOriginalFilePath);
    $video
        ->filters()
        ->watermark($imageFilePath, array(
            'position' => 'absolute',
            'x' => 100,
            'y' => 0,
    ));
    $video->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'output.mp4');
```

This is working fine this way but the problem is that I need this "$imageFilePath" to be not a real path, but an image created by imagick. Is there anyway that I can do it?

Comment: Sounds like this isn't really related to ffmpeg but to having a "file" that's really just something in memory, so... have a look at php://memory (or php://temp)? https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But I don't know how to do it. I have an Imagick object stored in a variable. What I want to do is overlay that object on the video. Is there any way that I can get the variable memory path or use the object itself with ffmpeg?

Comment: "write" that object to a file, except use `php://memory` as file name instead of a real file, and then use that same url instead of `$imageFilePath` in your code.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks mate, i'll post the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using the following code:

```
// create temp file
$temp = new SplTempFileObject();

// get its file path
$tempPath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $temp);

// open the file
$file = fopen($tempPath, "w");

// write the image to the temp file
$image->setImageFormat('png');
$image->writeImageFile($file);

// overlay the image using the temp file path
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open($video);
$video
  ->filters()
  ->watermark($tempPath, array(
  'position' => 'absolute',
    'x' => $xOffset,
    'y' => $yOffset,
  ));

$video->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'output.mp4');
```

Comment: Sure, if _actual_ temp files were fine to begin with, this would have been anyone's recommendation. But why not just use [`$file = tmpfile();`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) instead of manually bulding a fairly obscure SplTempfileObject with the equally obscure "tempnam" function? Also, remember to be intentional and `fclose($file)` after you're done with the temp file.